# How to mark 2 different rows that have same value in one column by using "Case"

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, case, multiple-columns

I'm trying to mark these deliveries orders if they were 'First', 'Second', 'Third' etc. out of 'Single-Route', 'Double-Route' or 'Triple-Route' using "Case" statement. 
Please help!

[image]

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Right now we don't even know what mark mean and neither what are those Routes

Comment: There are no `Case` statements in SQL Server; there is only the [`CASE` expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
Select case [Sort in Order]
when 'first' then 'Single-Route'
when 'second' then 'Double-Route'
when 'Third' then 'Triple-Route'
END as [New column alias] from [TableName]
```